# How to keep the notification drawer open after notification click in Android

Tags: android, notifications

I've noticed the drawer is auto closed when clicking the notification (click actually launches a service).
Is there a way of preventing the drawer from being closed?
Thanks.

Comment: Hi @SagiLow did you found anything yourself?

Comment: @JorgeGalvao unfortunately not ... I think I've seen some workaround when having root access, but it's not my goal